# How XSLT treats multiple nested element?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to convert some plain text with special marker into HTML formatted text.

For example,

This is the original value

```
Th&lt;italic&gt;is is a &lt;under&gt;com&lt;bold&gt;bina&lt;/bold&gt;tion&lt;/under&gt;&lt;/italic&gt; text.
```

The original value as actual value (just for reference)

```xml
Th<italic>is is a <under>com<bold>bina</bold>tion</under></italic> text.
```

HTML format I expect as a result

```xml
Th<i>is is a <u>com<b>bina</b>tion</u></i> text.
```

I tried with below template but it can not be parsed by XSLT parser.

```xml
<xsl:template name="decorateValue">
<xsl:param name="originalString" />

<xsl:variable name="preString" select="substring-before($originalString, '&lt;')" />
<xsl:variable name="postString" select="substring-after($originalString, '&lt;')" />

<xsl:value-of select="$preString" />

<xsl:variable name="tagName" select="substring-before($postString, '&gt;')" />

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='bold'">
            <xsl:element name="b">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='/bold'">
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='italic'">
            <xsl:element name="i">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='/italic'">
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='under'">
            <xsl:element name="u">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$tagName='/under'">
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:call-template name="decorateValue">
    <xsl:with-param name="originalString" 
                    select="substring-after($postString, '&gt;')" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

any idea to solve this?

I would appreciate in advance.

Comment: Is your input plain text? If it is, you need to at least place it within a pair of XML tags (ex: `<root>Th&lt;italic&gt;is...</root>`). Also, your XSLT document is incomplete. It won't work if you don't place your template inside an `<xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: You're essentially trying to implement a parser for a simple markup language in XSLT 1.0. I don't think it is the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can actually keep the original text, your life would be easier. Then you can transform
`Th<italic>is is a <under>com<bold>bina</bold>tion</under></italic> text.` easily into xHTML

```
<xsl:template match="italic">
    <xsl:element name="i">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You can't mix your tags in your example. You open an xsl:when and open an xsl:element and then close the xsl:when. That is not valid XML!

So if you want to go with the encoded string you need something like:

```
<xsl:template name="decorateValue">
    <xsl:param name="originalString" />

    <xsl:if test="$originalString!=''">

        <xsl:variable name="preString" select="substring-before($originalString, '&lt;')" />
        <xsl:variable name="postString" select="substring-after($originalString, '&lt;')" />
        <xsl:variable name="endString" select="'magic happens here!'" />

        <xsl:value-of select="$preString" />

        <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="substring-before($postString, '&gt;')" />
        <xsl:variable name="restString" select="'magic happens here!'" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tagName='bold'">
                <xsl:element name="b">
                    <xsl:call-template name="decorateValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="originalString" 
                            select="$restString" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$tagName='italic'">
                <xsl:element name="i">
                    <xsl:call-template name="decorateValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="originalString" 
                            select="$restString" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$tagName='under'">
                <xsl:element name="u">
                    <xsl:call-template name="decorateValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="originalString" 
                            select="$restString" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$endString" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You see 2 places where `'magic happens here'`. This is where you need to apply the string-before-last and string-after-last patterns (which are a PITA in XSLT). The best explanation can be found in the [XSLT Cookbook](http://users.atw.hu/xsltcookbook2/xsltckbk2-chp-2-sect-4.html) (and you want to have XSLT 2.0 at least.

Hope the pointers help. You might consider breaking the pattern into individual, so you don't fish for > alone, but the full tags. You still need to use the before-last / after-last functions.